# Book about an eskimo hunter becoming a member of thieves' guild

Tags: story-identification, books

Eskimo hunter becomes lost; starving, he kills a sacred talking animal. He is taken to city for judgment, where he passes thieves' guild entrance examination by standing in cold all night, and has many more adventures.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Was he specifically an "eskimo"?

Comment: Please clarify the ambiguous phrase "Eskimo hunter". Does he hunt Eskimos?

Comment: All I remember is he is a boy / young man, he lives in arctic conditions and lives a traditional hunter's life. Somehow he gets separated from his father / tribe and wanders until he is starving. He kills or at least wounds an elk(?)  for food - but  it turns out to be a talking, thinking being. For his 'crime' he is taken to a city. There he passes the entrance exam for guild membership by surviving a night standing outside in the cold.